# Double Click Element is not working with robot framework in FF

Tags: robotframework

My use case is , I need to `Double Click` on a input text then it opens a child browser there i have to select few details.

Now i am unable to double click on the input field itself.

My sample Code is as below:

```
   Double Click Element    id=simNumber
```

I got the error as below:

```
WebdriverException: Message: POST /session/sdfdfdfsf-werrsdfs-erwrw-02323-03424/moveto did not match a known command.
```

When i googled about this error, i comes to know that latest FF is not supporting mouse events, here the link [firefox mouse event issue](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2285)

Is there any work around for this, as i need to automate application in Firefox only.

Comment: Which Firefox/Geckodriver version do you have? I was lucky with Firefox 52.0 and v0.15.0 geckodriver.

Comment: Thanks PONKA, let me try on this

Comment: PONKA, can you post this as answer i will accept, thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to check versions of browser and geckodriver. Which Firefox/Geckodriver version do you have? I was lucky with Firefox 52.0 and v0.15.0 geckodriver.

You can find Mozilla Firefox here: https://www.mozilla.org
Newest geckodriver was found here: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases